# Remove Rack stack log on rackup

Tags: sinatra, rack

I'm running a Sinatra App and added some custom rack middleware before it.

My problem is, when I start my application the rackup command prints all the rack stack at the end of rack startup. Something similar to:

```
{:inner_app=>
#<NewRelic::Agent::Instrumentation::MiddlewareProxy:0x0055e978c28bb8
   @category=:middleware,
   @is_app=false,
   @target=
    #<Rack::Cors:0x0055e978c297c0
     @all_resources=
      [#<Rack::Cors::Resources:0x0055e978c29608
        @origins=["*"],
        @public_resources=true,
        @resources=
         [#<Rack::Cors::Resource:0x0055e978c292c0
           @credentials=true,
           @expose=["Location"],
           @headers=:any,
           @max_age=1728000,
           @methods=[:get, :post, :put, :delete, :options],
           @public_resource=true>]>]
...
}
```

I made a lab to reproduce it easily, it is [here](https://github.com/felipefujioka/rack-strange-log).

In my case, the rack stack comes with some instance values defined that contains some private information that should remain secret.

I just want to stop logging this to the stdout at least in deployment environment. Does someone know what prints it and if there is any configuration that can stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that we were passing '-d' flag to unicorn and it was printing some extra debug info.